# Result of a delete mutation?

Tags: graphql, graphql-ruby

What should be the result of a delete mutation in Graphql? I'm using the graphql-ruby gem. Here's an example of my mutation, but I'm just not sure what I should be returning as the response.

```
Mutations::Brands::Delete = GraphQL::Relay::Mutation.define do
  name "DeleteBrand"
  description "Delete a brand"

  input_field :id, types.ID

  # return_field ??

  resolve ->(object, inputs, ctx) {
    brand = Brand.find(inputs[:id])
    brand.destroy
  }
end
```

Comment: I think best practice is to return exactly what you deleted so that graphql knows what needs to go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return deleted_id or message. If it is an associated object you can return updated object like below example.

```
Destroy = GraphQL::Relay::Mutation.define do
name 'DestroyComment'
description 'Delete a comment and return post and deleted comment ID'

# Define input parameters
input_field :id, !types.ID

# Define return parameters
return_field :deletedId, !types.ID
return_field :article, ArticleType
return_field :errors, types.String

resolve ->(_obj, inputs, ctx) {
  comment = Comment.find_by_id(inputs[:id])
  return { errors: 'Comment not found' } if comment.nil?

  article = comment.article
  comment.destroy

  { article: article.reload, deletedId: inputs[:id] }
}
```

http://tech.eshaiju.in/blog/2017/05/15/graphql-mutation-query-implementation-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Would this not result in a memory bloat ? @eshaiju

Answer (score 38):

I don't think a clear de facto standard exists as of July, 2017, and I see a lot of differences between implementations (GitHub, Yelp, GraphCool, Shopify).

However, if you look at some of recent GraphQL APIs to come out, there seems to be a common trend.  Largely, the input type and response type are specific to the mutation.  So for instance, for an `updateBrand` mutation you might expect an `UpdateBrandInput`, and return an `UpdateBrandPayload` response.  Notice, the input is not `BrandInput`, and responding with `Brand`.  Nor would you respond with a scalar boolean (eg. `true` if successful) or the `id` of the deleted entity (in the case of a delete mutation).  Per this convention, you could have a `createBrand` mutation, with a `CreateBrandInput` and a `CreateBrandPayload` response.

By creating mutation specific `input` and `payload` types, you have a lot of flexibility in the fields you expect and respond with.  Per deletion, you might have a `DeleteBrandPayload` response that not only includes shallow (eg. only scalar) fields of the brand, but also other related data (eg. `clientMutationId`), etc..

To be honest, I think the GraphQL spec gives just enough rope to hang yourself with, so it's smart to look at how some of the big guys are rolling this out.

Comment: Funny thing: I was looking for exactly this answer (thank you, it was very useful), and as it happens, the mutations I'm working on are named "createBrand", "updateBrand" and "deleteBrand" :D

Comment: Would have been interesting to have the link of some examples of the "big guys" code you're talking about, they've dozens of repositories

Comment: You can try the GraphQL API from Github here https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer (you have to sign in), they use this naming: `DeleteBrandInput`, `DeleteBrandPayload`.